# Use short Python script in power query to scrape data from password protected site (-> Power BI)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, powerbi

I'm completely new to Python, so please apologize any "embarrassing code or questions". Actually I'm using R but I can't construct a code that does the following job for me. I switched to Python for this task because the following code already exists.

The problem: I want to **scrape** data from a website that is password protected and read that data into Power BI.

```
import requests
import json
import argparse
from typing import List
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

def login(mail: str, password: str) -> (int):
    login = requests.post(
        "https://kickbase.sky.de/api/v1/user/login", params={
            "email": mail,
            "password": password
        })
    if login.status_code == 200:
        return json.loads(login.text)["user"]["accessToken"]

    raise LoginError(mail, login.status_code)

auth_token = login("testuserscrape@web.de", "testuserscrape")

request = requests.get(
        f"https://api.kickbase.com/leagues/1420282/lineupex", headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}"})

players_json = json.loads(request.text)["players"]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(players_json, orient='columns')
```

I am interested in df.

When I run this code in Jupiter Notebook I get what I want:

[image: Output]

However, when I simply put this code into PowerBI -> Get Data -> Python Script, I get the following Error:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this issue and get my data into the Power BI Query?

Best!

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't installed pandas and other library. Try below code to install panda and other requirements.

Python2.x

```
pip install pandas typing requests matplotlib
```

Python3.x

```
pip3 install pandas typing requests matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check python path in the setting under option.

[image]

Then make sure you install libraries to run your script.